# Qt - update PaintGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, drawing

I have done some research trough the different threads about PaintGL on SO, but I couldn't manage to find what I need to make it work / understand completely.

I am trying to draw a cube. EVerytime my pushbutton gets clicked the cube should rotate. (only when it gets clicked, no timers etc)
To determine the angle I use the variable xAngle. I am able to modify it trough the function setAngleCube(), but my cube doesn't seem to move. (I see the var 'i' being changed every time.)
why? How could I make it work?

To me it looks like the cube just keeps its value from the constructor and doesn't modiy them any more.

solution:
add this line in the slot of the pushbutton
 ui->widget->setCubeAngle(ui->widget->getCubeAngle()+5);

credit to @Alexander Chernin

my code:

```
MyGLWidget::MyGLWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent)
{
    xRot = 0;
    yRot = 0;
    zRot = 0;
    xAngle=15;

   qDebug("constructor\n") ;

}
void MyGLWidget::setCubeAngle(int angle)
{
    xAngle = angle;
    qDebug("angle set\n");  
}

int MyGLWidget::getCubeAngle()
{
     return xAngle;
}

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
 Glptr = new MyGLWidget();
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   static int i;

   i+=5;
    Glptr->setCubeAngle(i); 
   update();
   qDebug()<<i<<endl;
ui->widget->setCubeAngle(ui->widget->getCubeAngle()+5); //SOLUTION
}


void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    qDebug("painting cube\n");
```

qDebug()<

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(getCubeAngle(),0.0,1.0,0.0); //rotate 30 degress around y-axis
    glRotatef(5.0,1,0.0,0.0); //rotate 15 degress around x-axis

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

 //back
       glColor3f(1,0,0);
       glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.2,-0.5 );
       glVertex3f(-0.7, 0.2,-0.5);
       glVertex3f(-0.7, -0.2,-0.5 );
       glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.2,-0.5);

//some similar code to draw other sides of the cube

}
```

Comment: getCubeAngle() returns void? Are you sure? Did you try to call updateGL() on mijnGlptr instead of update() on the parent?

Comment: sorry modified that typo. Well when I try updateGL, my program just doesn't start. I added this in the constructor of MyGLWidget :  mijntussenPtr = new MyGLWidget(); . and then in setangle:  mijntussenPtr ->updateGL();

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld
when I don't use a pointer and just call it directly, it doesn't crash but my cube doesn't move neither. xAngle just stays on 15 when the function paintGL gets called

Answer (score 1):

try to call updateGL() in  MyGLWidget::setCubeAngle:

```
 void MyGLWidget::setCubeAngle(int angle)
 {
    xAngle = angle;
    qDebug("angle set\n");  
    updateGL();
 }
```

Comment: I did this, but doenst work. When the the function paintGL gets called, the var xAngle stays 15. It doesn't get modified

Comment: спасибо. Я буду смотреть ;)

Comment: @the1liquid Пожалуйста ;)